# Is it true that $a$ can't be zero in the quadratic function $y=ax^2+bx+c$?

Tags: proof-verification, quadratics

I read that for $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is a quadratic function where $a\neq0$, but is it true that $a$ really can't be zero?  I think it is because if $a$ **was** zero, there wouldn't be a parabola.  There would just be a flat line, so then it wouldn't be quadratic because the $x^2$-term indicates if the parabola opens upward or downward.  Is this right or is it true about what I asked?

Comment: It seems like you answered your own question.

Comment: Just optionally do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a=0$, you no longer have a parabola.

Instead, you have a line: $y = bx+c$, with slope equal to $b$, and a $y$-intercept at $c$.

Comment: Yeah, your flat, regular, horizontal line.

Comment: Not necessarily horizontal (in which case slope equals zero.) It can be any line (depending on $b, c$.

Comment: $b=0$ and $c=2$, so $y=2$, which makes a horizontal line go through $(0, 2)$.

Comment: Well, when $a$ gets closer to $0$, the parabola becomes flatter.

Comment: Indeed, it does.

Comment: Okay, I get the line thing now.

Answer (score -2):

I guess I'm right.  If $a$ is zero, then $y=ax^2+bx+c$ would change to $y=bx+c$, leaving $b$ as the slope and $c$ as the y-intercept, leaving a flat line, not a parabola.